# delphi stringgrid inplaceedit how to position and width of edit box in a cell that has a left/right justified checkbox

Tags: delphi, inplace-editing, stringgrid

I have altered a D6 stringgrid to allow for left or right justified checkboxes to be displayed in the grid cells.  When the stock inplace editor is called the edit box for receiving data starts at the beginning of the cell and its width covers the entire width of the cell (ie it fills the cell completely covering my checkboxes until repainted).  How can I implement my own inplace editor and control the starting location of the editor and its width?  Thanks in advance to all.  Bill

Comment: sifu  I started looking into grids.pas and found whgetdialogcode, updatecontents, validate/invalidaterect, etc but could not pick out how the dimensions of the selected cell were being fed to a procedure for formatting the edit box;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TStringGrid` does not natively support what you are asking for.  The coordinates of the inplace editor are fixed to the entire cell bounds, as it was never designed to take user-defined cell controls into account.

When `TStringGrid` positions the editor, it calls `CellRect()` (which is not virtual) and passes the returned `TRect` to `TInplaceEdit.Move()` (which is not virtual), which calls `TInplaceEditor.InternalMove()` (which is private) to move the editor HWND to the specified coordinates and size using the Win32 API `SetWindowPos()` function.

The only way you will be able to change that logic is to either:

1. make a copy of `Grids.pas` and alter `TStringGrid`'s source code, then add the modified file to your project (this only works if Runtime Packages are disabled).
2. use a hook/detour to redirect `TInplaceEdit.Move()` to a custom method where you can alter the content of the `TRect` before passing it to the original implementation.

**Update**: now that I think more about it, you might be able to derive a class from `TInplaceEdit` and override its virtual `WndProc()` method to calculate different position/size information when asked by the `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` or `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` message.  Or override its virtual `BoundsChanged()` method to reposition/resize the editor after the grid has positioned/sized the editor where it wants. Either way, you can override the virtual `TStringGrid.CreateEditor()` method to make the grid create an instance of your editor class.

Comment: Remy. Not sure how to conduct a hook/detour of TInplaceEdit.Move.

Comment: Can you explain?  Is this just a cracker class and override of the Move procedure?

Comment: Remy  InplaceEdit.Move is only called by TCustomGrid.UpdateEdit.  Would my solution be to cracker class TCustomGrid AND TStringGrid and override the UpdateEdit of the TCustomGrid cracker class to feed the overridden coordinates of my desired TRect edit box downstream?

Comment: A cracker class will not work. `UpdateEdit()` is not virtual, so you cannot override it. And `Move()` is called on a `TInplaceEdit` variable, and `Move()` is not virtual either. No, the only way to redirect `Move()` is to use a lower-level VMT hook or detour.

Comment: Remy  Thank you for taking the time to explain. I will try your #1 suggestion above about copying Grids.pas and modifying for my needs then come back and look later at #2 just for giggles.  Bill